# Navigating to another page in Stream Builder only once if stream of data is coming

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I am using Stream builder to receive data from Esp32 BLE to my Flutter Application, I am detecting seizures in my app so I have used a condition of currentValue = 2 if a seizure occurs and navigate to the other page. But the other page is called many times until the current value = 2 stops coming.
How can I **call the page only one time** if the condition satisfies and the value '2' keeps coming?

This is my `code of Stream Builder` where page is called when current Value becomes 2:

```
StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
                                    stream: stream,
                                    initialData: lastValue,
                                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                                        AsyncSnapshot<List<int>> snapshot) {
                                      if (snapshot.hasError)
                                        return Text(
                                          'Error: ${snapshot.error}',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
                                            fontSize: 19,
                                            color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                            height: 1.4736842105263157,
                                          ),
                                        );

                                      if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                          ConnectionState.active) {
                                        //var currentValue = _dataParser(snapshot.data);
                                        var currentVal =
                                            snapshot.data.toString();
                                        int currentValue = int.parse(
                                            currentVal.substring(
                                                1, currentVal.length - 1),
                                            onError: (source) => -1); // 33
                                        print("String data $currentValue");
                                        if (currentValue == 2) {
                                          return FutureBuilder(
                                              future: Future.delayed(
                                                const Duration(seconds: 0),
                                                () async {
                                                  Seziurealert();
                                                }
                                              ),
                                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                                // setState(() {
                                                //   currentValue = 0;
                                                // });
                                                return Text(
                                                  'Seizure Occurred',
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
                                                    fontSize: 19,
                                                    color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                    height: 1.4736842105263157,
                                                  ),
                                                );
                                              });
                                        } else if (currentValue == 0) {
                                          return Text(
                                            'Device not calibrated',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
                                              fontSize: 19,
                                              color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                              height: 1.4736842105263157,
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        } else if (currentValue == 1) {
                                          return Text(
                                            '$currentValue',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
                                              fontSize: 19,
                                              color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                              height: 1.4736842105263157,
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        }
                                        return Text(
                                          '$currentValue',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
                                            fontSize: 19,
                                            color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                            height: 1.4736842105263157,
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      } else {
                                        return Text(
                                          'Check the stream',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
                                            fontSize: 19,
                                            color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                            height: 1.4736842105263157,
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
```

Seizure Alert function:

```
Seziurealert(){
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return TriggeringAlert(
              device:
              widget.device);
        },
      ),
          (route) => false,
    );

  }
```

I also tried using this but the same was happening as it is with Future Builder:

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                                            Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                              context,
                                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                                builder: (context) {
                                                  return TriggeringAlert(
                                                      device:
                                                      widget.device);
                                                },
                                              ),
                                                  (route) => false,
                                            );
```

This is the image of my page that is called when Value 2 occurs. This page keeps on showing until 10s of timer are over or I press the cancel button. But in my case even if the timer's 10 seconds are over the page is called again OR if I press the cancel button, the page is also called again in that case.

[image]

Please help me how can I avoid that as I am new to Flutter

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `Stream`, you can use a `Future`. For example, you can use `Stream.firstWhere` to get a `Future` that will complete only when a specific predicate is met.

In your case, it would be something like:

```dart
final future = stream.map((value) {
  final currentVal = value.toString();
  final currentParsedVal = int.parse(
    currentVal.substring(1, currentVal.length - 1),
    onError: (source) => -1,
  );
  print("String data $currentParsedVal");
  return currentParsedVal;
}).firstWhere((value) => value == 2);
```

Then, you can wait for this future and navigate to wherever you want when it's complete in your `initState`, for example.

Comment: But i want is that as soon as the 2 comes it should navigate to the Trigger Screen where Timer starts

Comment: Are you saying that i should remove Stream Builder?

Comment: Sorry i am new to Flutter i am unable to understand what you wanted me to do instead?

Comment: Yes, exactly. As soon as there is a 2 in your stream, you will navigate.

Comment: i removed stream builder but it showed me an error with your code because this stream builder is inside a column widget

Comment: The snippet I proposed is supposed to be in another place, for example, in the `initState`, and not inside your `build` method.

Comment: how can i use "future" to navigate to another page?

Comment: when 2 comes if I use your snippet? could you elaborate it further please :)

Comment: Also how can I use the currentValue in any Widget?